# what should we add to a 2-3 tree to be able to find a value with this time complexity?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, trees

I've got this question that asks me to make changes to the 2-3 trees that would make it possible to do a find(x) function that would find x with O(log(rank(x))) .

**rank(x) is x's index in a sorted sequence of all of the values of the tree. However we have to still do insert(x) and delete(x) with O(log(n)).

So I thought of using pointers, that would make it easier to find the wanted value and yet I have no Idea how to do it with the requested time complexity.

If you have an idea that may direct me to the solution , please share it.

Comment: Please state or refer the definition of *2-3 tree* to use.

Comment: @greybeard deleted it from SO

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean by *definition* isn't it just one? a B+ tree

Comment: I am used to *find in a data structure* to mean *given a* $key$ ($x$?), *find the associated* $record$. Starting with [*B-trees*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), I'm used to *All leaves have same depth*. With *rank(x)* starting from 0 or 1, $O(\log(rank(x)))$ looks impossible. There are augmented trees allowing access to records *by rank* in time $O(\log(n))$.

Comment: @greybeard rank(x) starting from 1,and All leaves have same depth... so you think there is no solution?